# SQL still have duplicates after Group By

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get a grand total of the qty_on_hand between our 2 warehouses combined but after I do a group by the totals don't combine.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
SELECT 
    sku_master.warehouse,
     sku_master.sku
   , sku_master.min_on_hand
   , sku_master.max_on_hand
   , x.total_qty_on_hand

FROM [wms].dbo.[sku_master]

left join
(
  SELECT 
     sku_master.sku, sum(location_inventory.qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand
  FROM [wms].[dbo].[location_inventory]
JOIN [wms].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
      GROUP BY sku_master.sku) x on sku_master.sku = x.sku
```

Results

[image: Results]

Expected Results

[image: Expected Results]

Comment: Those arent duplicates

Comment: There are obviously two records for sku 10328579 in sku_master, so you get two result rows. What else do you want?

Comment: When I say they are duplicates it's because the SKU is the same.  So if the SKU is the same I want to group them together and sum the total_qty_on_hand.

Comment: The SKU is the same because you have included the warehouse in the join and that SKU exists in multiple warehouses. In other words you have a row per SKU, per warehouse.

Comment: What should your result contain for `warehouse`, `min_on_hand` and `max_on_hand` when you only show one row for the sku?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That question just hit the light bulb.   for min_on_hand / max_on_hand should be based off the XDGM warehouse.

Comment: @eternityhq - can you post sample data and \expected result

Comment: @Prdp I've added the expected results.

Comment: @eternityhq - why did you choose 0 and 3 for min and max hand instead of `1` and `3`

Comment: @Prdp because one's a remote location and the other in a close source.

Comment: @eternityhq - added answer.. though am not 100% clear on min and max hand. but total will happen correctly

Comment: @Prdp It's a tough one to explain.  The min_on_hand and max_on_hand are there to show if the sku(s) are in a min state or max state based on the qty_on_hand.   There are other columns in sku_master for stdpack.  Which I programmatically multiply or divide against.   Just the one warehouse (dst) isn't the master data that we need.  That's contained in the XDGM warehouse.

Comment: @eternityhq - Check my answer once.

Comment: With SQL questions you should always tag your DBMS. Is this for SQL Server?

Comment: `sku_master` has a column `warehouse`. Your query suggests that `location_inventory` on the other hand only relates to an SKU and not to a particular warehouse. Is this correct? (It usually helps with SQL queries to show the table structures, i.e. tables with columns and unique keys.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want sum all `qty_on_hand` for each `sku`. Try something like this using `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT m.sku,
       m.min_on_hand,
       m.max_on_hand,
       oa.total_qty_on_hand
FROM   (SELECT sku,
               Min(min_on_hand) min_on_hand,
               Max(max_on_hand) max_on_hand
        FROM   [wms].dbo.[sku_master] m
        GROUP  BY sku) m
       OUTER Apply (SELECT Sum(l.qty_on_hand) AS total_qty_on_hand
                    FROM   [wms].[dbo].[location_inventory] l
                    WHERE  l.sku = m.sku) oa
```

Comment: this query will  return `total_qty_on_hand  = 15000!` and that is not the same as he mentioned in his question!

Answer (score 0):

If you need  only the grand total then don't join  or just for sample add with a union this

```
  SELECT 
      sku_master.warehouse,
       sku_master.sku
     , sku_master.min_on_hand
     , sku_master.max_on_hand
     , x.total_qty_on_hand

  FROM [wms].dbo.[sku_master]

  left join
  (
    SELECT 
       sku_master.sku, sum(location_inventory.qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand
    FROM [wms].[dbo].[location_inventory]
  JOIN [wms].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
        GROUP BY sku_master.sku) x on sku_master.sku = x.sku
  union 

  SELECT null, null, nullm null, sum(location_inventory.qty_on_hand)
  FROM [wms].[dbo].[location_inventory]
  JOIN [wms].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
```

or do the fact you  have sku_master.warehouse not grouped  and repeated .. remove it form select

```
  SELECT 
       sku_master.sku
     , sku_master.min_on_hand
     , sku_master.max_on_hand
     , x.total_qty_on_hand

  FROM [wms].dbo.[sku_master]

  left join
  (
    SELECT 
       sku_master.sku, sum(location_inventory.qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand
    FROM [wms].[dbo].[location_inventory]
  JOIN [wms].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
        GROUP BY sku_master.sku) x on sku_master.sku = x.sku
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple query

```
 SELECT 
  t.sku, 
  min(t.min_on_hand)  as min_qty_on_Hand,
  max(t.max_on_hand) as max_on_hand,
  sum(t.total_qty_on_hand) + sum(t2.total_qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand
FROM table1 t
inner join table2 t2
 on t.sku = t2.sku
group by t.sku
```

the attached image shows the process including the result

Note: the result here is same as you mentioned in your question and what you need here just change the table names into your table name

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your request's comments you explain that you prefer one warehouse over the other. In this case you should have a table containing the warehouses with a column for the priority. Thus the query wouldn't have to know about warehouse priorities. (Just imagine you add a warehouse some day - you'd have to change all your queries.)

My query aggregates sku_master records per SKU and warehouse and then picks the best warehouse per SKU. It then joins the aggregated inventory rows by SKU.

Here is the query without a warehouse table.

```
select
  m.warehouse,
  m.sku,
  m.total_min_on_hand,
  m.total_max_on_hand,
  li.total_qty_on_hand
from
(
  select 
    sku, 
    warehouse,
    sum(min_on_hand) as total_min_on_hand,
    sum(max_on_hand) as total_max_on_hand,
    row_number() over (partition by sku 
                       order by case when warehouse = 'XDGM'  then 1 else 2 end) as rn
  from sku_master
  group by sku
) m
join
(
  select sku, sum(qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand
  from location_inventory
  group by sku
) li on li.sku = m.sku
where m.rn = 1; -- only the better warehouse when there is more than one for the SKU
```

With a warehouse table the from clause would slightly change to:

```
from
(
  select 
    sku, 
    warehouse,
    sum(min_on_hand) as total_min_on_hand,
    sum(max_on_hand) as total_max_on_hand,
    row_number() over (partition by sku order by w.priority) as rn
  from sku_master sm
  join warehouse w on w.warehouse = sm.warehouse
  group by sku
) m
```